# AngularJS how to filter an element in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this massive

```
$scope.arrVaritions = [
    [1, 2, 3], 
    [4, 5, 6], 
    [7, 8, 9], 
    [1, 4, 7], 
    [2, 5, 8], 
    [3, 6, 9], 
    [1, 5, 9], 
    [3, 5, 7]
];
```

How can I find an element index in this array? I'm use this code, but it does not work:

```
$scope.elementId = 1;    
$filter('filter')($scope.arrVaritions, { $scope.elementId });
```

Comment: yep not work. SyntaxError: Unexpected token "."

Comment: $filter('filter')($scope.arrVaritions, { id: $scope.elementId }); - it works, but i have not "ID"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try filter it in the right way like in this [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1365c5nL/1/):

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  {{filtered}}
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.arrVaritions = [
        [1, 2, 3], 
        [4, 5, 6], 
        [7, 8, 9], 
        [1, 4, 7], 
        [2, 5, 8], 
        [3, 6, 9], 
        [1, 5, 9], 
        [3, 5, 7]
    ];

    $scope.elementId = 1;
    $scope.filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.arrVaritions, $scope.elementId, true);
});
```

If you want to filter **not the exact value** just remove the 3rd `true` option:

```
$scope.filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.arrVaritions, $scope.elementId);
```

Comment: Exact same time :) `2017-03-12 10:32:10Z`

Comment: Yes, I was laughing loud in that moment. =)

Comment: upvoted! but I covered corner case :) which I faced usually while working on projects :)

Answer (score 1):

It should have only `$scope.elementId` instead of object, and 3rd option `true` to match exact value. Otherwise without `true` if `elementId` will consider `10`, `11`, `100`, etc. values (it will do contains check).

```
$filter('filter')($scope.arrVaritions, $scope.elementId, true);
```